# How can I access the Horizon:Error Response after raising error in code

Tags: stellar-sdk, error

After an error raised during a Transaction submission with **server.submit_transaction()** how can I access the corresponding **(Horizon Response JSON object)** https://developers.stellar.org/api/errors/response/ in my App's code in order to investigate the **"result_codes"** entry and handle the cause of the error(e.g: tx_insufficient_fee), programatically without halting the execution of my code forcefully (which is what happens now).

Stay Safe

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, let's share it with ya'll.
One should use **BaseHorizonError** to catch Exceptions, then iterate **extras.get("result_codes")** entry of the Exception's instance.
I've caught its sub-classes **(exceptions.BadRequestError, exceptions.BadResponseError, etc.)** so far, which seems doesn't contain these atrributes.
PEACE V